# Get git code commit Id's and WorkItem Id's for the current Build

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are using VSTS (Azure DevOps) git for code management of our Java code. We are also using VSTS Build definition to build our code.

In one of VSTS Task step we need code commit id's this build is building (Code Commit id after last success Build), associated Workitem Id's.

Do we have any VSTS task in Marketplace to handle this?

Else, If I need to write my own logic, how do I start?

Comment: I guess it is not a question about git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the predefined build variable `$(Build.SourceVersion)` to get the current commit ID during the build, please see [Build variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?tabs=batch&view=vsts#build-variables) for details.

Then you can run scripts to call the REST API ([Commits - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/commits/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1)) to get the associated Workitem Ids from the comment:

```
GET https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}?api-version=4.1
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this way we can get the WI's associated with a commit.

Comment: However i checked the triggerInfo object and found its always empty for all builds.  Any other way to get all commit Id's?

Comment: What's that mean for "`triggerInfo object`" and "`get all commit Id's`" here? How and where did you get the info? Generally only one version of the sources (Commit ID) needed to trigger the build.

Comment: Got it. All Commit I'd between previous success build and commit I'd of current build I use.